# Do ATA security commands include one for write protection?

Tags: hard-drive, security, sata, ata

ATA drives include a security command set that can be disabled until the next power cycle by a "security freeze" command. Does this security command set include one that enables write protection?

My goal is to use the two in conjunction to write protect a drive and have it remain write protected until the computer is reset.

See the power-on write protection feature of eMMCs and NVMe drives for a similar capability.

Comment: According to [ATA Command Matrix - OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_Command_Matrix), the answer is no.

Comment: @DavidPostill It does support protecting regions from both reads and writes though, right?